# Remove Duplicates in traditional LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I know there are better ways to do this with hashSets..etc, But I would like to do this the old way. Here is the function I wrote to eliminate duplicates, a tricky case was if the duplicate was very last node, I had to write a special case for it. Am I doing this correctly, I feel it's too hacky.

```
// Assume list like this: 0->1->2->3->4->0
//and want to remove 0 in this example
  //O(n^2)
public void removeDuplicatesV1(){
  Node current, itr;
  itr = head;
  if(head !=null){
      while(itr!=null && itr.getNext()!=null){  //ptr1
          current = itr;
          while(current.getNext()!=null){   //ptr2
              if(itr.getItem().equals(current.getNext().getItem())){
                  if(current.getNext().getNext()== null){ //look ahead if last node is a dup
                      current.setNext(null);              
                      break;
                  }
                  else
                      current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
              }
              current = current.getNext();
          }
          itr = itr.getNext();
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: One note is that you don't need the inner-most if statement. If current.getNext().getNext() is null, that's fine, you'll set current.setNext(null) in that case.

EDIT: In which case, you should only set current = current.getNext() if you do _not_ remove the next element. So, the second-to-inner-most if statement add an "else" clause and do the current = current.getNext() only in the else.

Comment: I don't follow, the innermost if clause is what's causing the dup to be removed in case it was the very last node. I don't think I can remove that line and still get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove itr.getNext()!=null from the first while loop.

```
// Assume list like this: 0->1->2->3->4->0
//Code below won't remove the last 0
//O(n^2)
public void removeDuplicatesV1(){
  Node current, itr;
  itr = head;
  if(head !=null){
      while(itr!=null ){  //slow ptr for outer loop, will be checked against fast pointer
          current = itr;
          while(current != null && current.getNext()!=null){ //inner loop, current ptr moves  down the list
              if(itr.getItem() == current.getNext().getItem())
                  current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
              current = current.getNext();
          }
          itr = itr.getNext();
      }
  }
```

Comment: No, that would cause it crash.

Comment: Added current != null condition inside while loop. Can you check this ?